# Multiple routers with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, router

Can I use multiple routers in `backbone.js`, that don't interfere with each other route-wise, without any issues?  Or is there something that I should be concerned about?

Code sample:

```
myapp.routers.main = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : { "": "index" },
    index : function() { console.log("routed by main router");}    
});

myapp.routers.another = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : { "notmain": "index" },
    index : function() { console.log("routed by another router");}    
});

mainrouter = new vaikava.routers.main;
notmainrouter = new vaikava.routers.another;
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: The easiest way to answer this question is to try it out and see if it works. As far as I know there should be no problem with what you've outlined.

Comment: I tried it myself - no errors, but as this is my first real backbone app and I've read that there could be issues with multiple routers, I wanted to ask here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it works just fine; the only time you'd have a problem is if they have conflicting routes. [There is a workaround](http://colonelpanic.net/2011/09/backbone-js-attaching-multiple-routers-to-the-same-route/) that makes it work that way as well, but it's a bit of a hack.

As long as you avoid having multiple routers trying to handle the same route you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Taxillian. Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you check out another related `backbone.js`-question for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957543/working-with-state-in-backbone-js-logging-in-a-user